# Auxiliary executable possible on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

On OS X, it's trivial to add an additional executable inside your application bundle. Is this possible on iOS, and if so, is it permitted by Apple (private framework calls via `objc_msgSend` are *possible*, but not *permitted*)?

The iOS version of the `NSBundle` class includes [the relevant APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForAuxiliaryExecutable:), but there are no templates in Xcode for a "command line tool", or even an empty target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but very restricted. It's only allowed for [defined extension types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/). The iOS bundle structure has a very [strict definition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW15) and [loadable bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW30) are not allowed.